# How to access LINQ results

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to using LINQ and I am having trouble accessing the results of this query. The goal is to use the values of the results elsewhere.

```
var orderFacts = new OrdersFactsController().getOrderFacts(base.ModuleId);
var f = (from x in orderFacts 
         where x.Language == lang 
         select new 
                { 
                  x.PRN, 
                  x.ProdCode, 
                  x.KeyCodes,  
                  x.JobNumber, 
                  x.OfferingCode, 
                  x.Currency, x.ID, 
                  x.OrderSourceCode 
                });
```

The query is returning results as I can see them when debugging, but I don't know how to use the results.

I thought it would be as easy as something like:

```
var prn = f.PRN
```

But it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You're returning an `IEnumerable<T>` of an anonymous type. Can you give an example of where/how you want to use this?

Comment: @JonB is correct - `f` should be an IEnumerable of a type, not a single instance of the type.

Comment: Also note that anonymous types are specifically designed to be used within the scope of a single method.  If you want to expose the results of the query externally you'll want to create a named type that you create a collection/sequence of rather than using an anonymous type.  Oh, and I'd throw some linebreaks into that query rather than putting it all on one line.

Comment: @JonB var orderFacts is a Ienumerable return from PetaPoco that contains all rows from a db table. The linq query is to trim the results down to only one. The values of the results are being used to populate some form fields.

Comment: @MarkHollas your LINQ query is also returning an IEnumerable. Like in Wouter's answer, you need to call `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, or `SingleOrDefault()` (depending on the behavior you want) to get your actual object.

Comment: @TimMedora What would an example look like of f being an IEnumerable? Thanks

Comment: See @WouterdeKort's answer. He shows you how to iterate over `f` when it is `IEnumerable`, or to retrieve a single value from `f`.

Comment: The answer seems to have worked and thanks to everyones comments I am getting a better understanding of why it does.

Comment: @JonB, Nice name!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `f` is not a single value with the projected properties you selected.

Instead the type of `f` is `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your newly created object (you can see this in Visual Studio by hovering with your mouse over *var*). If you are certain that there is only one resulting object you can use `SingleOrDefault()` on `f` like this:

```
var obj = f.SingleOrDefault();
```

If `f` could contain multiple objects, you can iterate over them with a `foreach` statement:

```
foreach(var obj in f)
{
    var prn = obj.PRN;
}
```